# Slate vs ProseMirror

Tags: richtextbox, rich-text-editor, slate.js, prose-mirror

I need to build a rich text editor for my React app. After a month of playing with Draft.js, I discovered it isn't configurable enough to suit my needs. I am deciding between **Slate** and **ProseMirror**.

What are the pros and cons of either of them?

Comment: can you provide a follow up? Which one did you choose and how did it went?

Comment: I played with Slate a little and gave it a try without diving too much into ProseMirror. And since then it hasn't let me down. A lot of things can be customized, it has an amazing API for traversing and manipulating its model and the code looks clean and concise. From what I read, ProseMirror is more powerful (it has a doublick detection, for example), but the anything that can be done there, can be done in Slate as well. The learning curve of Slate is very mild. Both have some minor bugs. I read one article of sb. migrating from ProseMirror to Slate. All in all, I highly recommend Slate.

Comment: You're welcome. To correct myself: ProseMirror has *triple click* detection, not just  double click. That would not be worthy of mentioning.

Comment: @AdamLibuša do you happen to remember the article about migrating from ProseMirror to Slate?

Comment: @mowwwalker I don't remember anymore, unfortunately